# How to get the id of a field in jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a one page then the page are composed of one .aspx file and one .ascx file.

Now in .ascx file I have declared a textbox as shown below.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="OrderName" MaxLength="50"  Key="OrderNameText" meta:resourcekey="OrderNameResource1">
```

Now I want to get the ID of this Textbox from my javascript, so i tried $("#OrderName") but it won't work.

As I check the code in the firebug I noticed that the id of this textbox is "ctl00_ctl00_contentPlaceHolderBody_contentPlaceHolderBelowFramedContainer_ucOrderName_OrderName".  It has been appended by some words.

So how to get the id in this given case?

Thanks

Jason

Comment: If you want help from people that don't know ASP, you need to show us what the generated HTML is (what the browser sees, not what your template is).

Comment: Inspect element in browser first... and tell us about the code.

Comment: since the id is dynamic, you could select the element by using other selectors or combination of selectors (class/attributes/tag name/position) and then access it's `id` attribute : `$('input[type=checkbox]:eq(3)').attr('id')`

Answer (score 1):

Access it via [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) or you can specify [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) to `static` while declaring your ASP.Net Control

```
  alert($("#'<%=OrderName.ClientID %>'").val());
```

Comment: this works fine but I don't want to have the ID declared as static by its ClientIDMode.. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
 var journalTextBoxId = '<%= this.OrderName.ClientID %>';
 var journalId = $("#" + journalTextBoxId).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the User Control, create a public property using C# like:

```
public string OrderNameClientID { get { return this.OrderName.ClientID; } }
```

In the JS of the current page access it like:

```
var ID = document.getElementById('<%= this.ucOrderName.OrderNameClientID %>');
```

Or you can simply do something like:

```
var ID = document.getElementById('<%= this.ucOrderName %>_OrderName');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact ID of your controls try this:

```
var $ID = $this.find('#<%= OrderName.ClientID %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using visual studio 2010 then you use like this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="OrderName" ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="50"  Key="OrderNameText" meta:resourcekey="OrderNameResource1"></asp:TextBox>
```

when you use like this then your text box id will not change like below

```
"ctl00_ctl00_contentPlaceHolderBody_contentPlaceHolderBelowFramedContainer_ucOrderName_OrderName"
```

so you should use ClientIDMode="Static" with your textbox and in jquery use like below

```
$("#OrderName")
```

i think this will help you.